# Detection Mouse Browser Navigation Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-plugins, mousewheel

I have to detect mouse browser navigations. Like "Apple Magic Mouse" swipes.

[image: magic mouse browser back swipe]

It's like horizontal scrolling but it is different.

[image: jquery mousewheel delta directions and variables]

JQuery Mousewheel plugin has two (left wheel = top wheel, right wheel = bottom wheel) different value, i need four (left, right, top, bottom).

*How* can i detect **only** left and right?